# How to safely execute batch file viruses for practice?

Tags: windows, virus, batch

I'm following a tutorial on [fork bomb](http://xeushack.com/fork-bomb) and thought it was pretty interesting. TL;DR: It's basically just a program that replicates itself until the computer freezes/crashes.

I want to see how it actually looks like when executing but don't want to screw up my computer. What's a safe way to try out batch file viruses?

Comment: Do it in a virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run it in a virtual machine. A virtual machine emulates a computer on your computer. You can give it a limited amount of resources (CPU's, memory) and the environment on the virtual machine can not access the computer it runs on. Popular software to run virtual machines are [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and [VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot. Hmmm, any idea if there's a non-piracy way to get virtual images for windows?

Comment: @MrRobot You can find test images of Windows [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/). Just select the version of Windows, and then the virtualization platform.